# Wordpress - How to prioritize some stylesheets when enqueueing them

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress theme.

My theme uses bootstrap and another framework, plus some custom CSS as well.

I'd like to know if there's a way to decide the order of the stylesheets to include so that my custom CSS is loaded ALWAYS after the vendor ones.

I had a look around, also this question is basically asking the same thing as I am ([Ordering Wordpress Stylesheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896536/ordering-wordpress-stylesheets)) but the problem is that it's not a nice and clean solution in my opinion.

I don't want to use important on everything to override, and I don't want to manually add my styles to the header.php (the wp_enqueue_style function is there for a reason, and I'd like to use that function instead).

Reading the documentation, the only thing that may be slightly related is the use of the deps array, but I'm not sure it will do what I need.

here's the link to the documentation or your reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

the way I enqueue my stylesheets now is pretty basic:

in my functions.php:

```
function hw_resources()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome-css', '/wp-content/themes/hwTheme/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bulma-css', '/wp-content/themes/hwTheme/assets/css/bulma.css');
//    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', '/wp-content/themes/hwTheme/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('animate-css', '/wp-content/themes/hwTheme/assets/css/animate.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('hw-css', '/wp-content/themes/hwTheme/assets/css/hw.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('hw-js', '/wp-content/themes/hwTheme/assets/js/hw.js', array(), false, false);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hw_resources', 0);
```

The stylesheets are included, but mine (hw.css) is NOT the last one and so Bulma (which goes at the bottom) overrides some of my custom style.

any suggestions? Is the deps array useful for this reason? how do I use it?

thanks

Comment: you prob should combine your stylesheets anyway for pagespeed! Also async loading is seen as faster than sync..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can set your `bulma.css` as a ***`dependency`*** on your `hw.css`.
So first you register your css via `wp_register_style` and then you use `wp_enqueue_style`.

Like so:

```
function hw_resources()
{
 wp_register_style( 'hw-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/hw.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
 wp_register_style( 'bulma-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bulma.css', array( 'hw-css' ), '1.0', 'all' );
 wp_enqueue_style('hw-css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hw_resources');
```