# (Wordpress) Can't change homepage menu color, but can change other page menu colors

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm using Wordpress with a theme that uses Elementor and Astra. I can change the menu colors, and it works on all pages, except the home page. Is there a way I can force certain css properties on the homepage menu? I've scoured all the theme settings, elementor settings, astra settings, all the settings, I can't find anything.

Comment: !important tag also not worked?

Comment: if not work can you provide your site link ? or share the code you have tried?

Comment: It's probably a matter of precedence, where your new rule is declared and later overwritten by the original rule executed further down in the markup. Adding `!important`, while frowned upon, might be the quickest and easiest solution. Some good information can also be found in other questions such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896536/ordering-wordpress-stylesheets

Comment: I'll try using !important. The website is https://drugsnothugs.co/

Answer (score 0):

you must provide you site link to find the style

or by inspect tools fine class name and style to your nav menu

if you change it and is not work ... 
check `ctrl+f5`

Comment: ok you must get color for this class **ast-theme-transparent-header .main-header-menu a** on css file for other menu item and for **current** menu color should set color for this class **ast-theme-transparent-header .main-header-menu .current-menu-item>a**

Comment: @atychi check top comment and set style in css file and then it must worked for you