# Wordpress enqueue multiple stylesheets before </head> tag

Tags: php, wordpress, function, stylesheet, enqueue

I want to load multiple css files into wordpress right before the closing head tag. The following code works, but it's being overruled by another stylesheet that is just before the closing head tag:

```
    function alt_styles()     
{    
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bb-style', '/wp-content/uploads/bb-style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bb-landing', '/wp-content/uploads/bb-second-style.css' ); 
}

add_filter( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'alt_styles', 10000000000 );
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get these 2 styles lower in the dom (just before the closing head tag)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordering Wordpress Stylesheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896536/ordering-wordpress-stylesheets)

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7897325/2355051  See if that works.

Comment: it should be `add_action` and use `wp_print_styles`

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't work :( We want two css files to load just before the closing head tag. In your examples it's only 1 file. We already got it working with other code to load before the closing tag. But we can't get 2 css files to load before the closing tag. It would be perfect if someone knew what the code should be

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp_head to add scripts manually.

```php
// Add scripts to wp_head()
function child_theme_head_script() { ?>
    <!-- This is injected last -->
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'child_theme_head_script', 999 );
```

You will need to include the path to the script yourself

[image]

Comment: What code do we need to add here? Can you complete the code? It doesn't work now. Where do we include a path? Could you make it complete and then we only change the 
path to the right location.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot where it is placing that comment then? That code 100% works. I use it all the time with a number of different themes.